# Integrating YouTube APis in asp.net mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, youtube-api, identity

How to configure my web app (Asp.NET MVC)!? 
I use identity with Google login, but I don't understand how to configure my app. 
Because in the documentation have 2 samples, but I don't understand how is good config my Apis!?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register your application in Google Developer console.

Next, after authentication succeeded, you will have to send a request to YouTube Api with the obtained tokens a client ID and secret

You can try out these from the Google Api playground best before coding.

Link: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/